# How to force an alignment error when casting a u8[] in a u16?

Tags: c++, c, alignment

I was trying , when answering a question, to warn the OP against **alignment** problems.

But when doing my snippet to show the OP how it can happens, I was unable to make it happen.

When running this code (C/C++) on an [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/), **I would expect it to fail**.

Why is it not?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

#define SIZE 20
int main()
{
    uint8_t in[20];
    in[0] = 0;
    in[1] = 1;//8bit
    in[2] = 1;
    in[3] = 1;//16bit
    in[4] = 1;
    in[5] = 1;
    in[6] = 1;
    in[7] = 1;//32bit
    in[8] = 1;
    in[9] = 1;
    in[10] = 1;
    in[11] = 1;
    in[12] = 1;
    in[13] = 1;
    in[14] = 1;
    in[15] = 1;//64bit
    in[16] = 1;
    in[17] = 1;
    in[18] = 1;
    in[19] = 1;
    uint16_t out;

    for (int i =0; i < SIZE - 2; i++)
    {
        out = *((uint16_t*)&in[i+1]);
        std::cout <<  "&in: " << (void*)&in[i+1] <<  "\n out: " << out << "\n in: " << in[i+2]*256 + in[i+1]<< std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Misalignment is more of a problem on some platforms than it is on others. What platform are you running this on, what problems were you expecting, and why?

Comment: Modern CPUs easily handle accessing whole words on odd/uneven addresses. It's a lot slower, but it will not cause a trap, like on older CPUs.

Comment: please do not remove the C tag as it is true in C... (just change the cout to printf)

Comment: I expect it to fall because on a ARM i already made it fail by accessing a mis-aligned 16 bit data...

Comment: please explain down voting? and yes the code can be compiled as C. just change the cout, the printf, and add <stdint.h>

Comment: On some it will work, on some it won't work, on others it might work - depending on how you've configured it. I've recently worked with an ARM Cortex-A5 device which would Fault on misaligned accesses if its MMU module was not enabled, but would work just fine with misaligned accesses if the MMU was enabled (because the MMU would translate the misaligned access into 2 separate aligned accesses and then combine the results of those into what was asked for). In the past I've worked with (as far as I remember) a dsPIC device which would consistently fail on misaligned accesses.

Comment: @GuillaumeD If it's not C code, it's not C code. C and C++ don't necessarily have the same rules, so their behaviour is not necessarily identical.

Comment: that's a bit harsh, have you tried to run the C code? it's not working not in C nor in C++, it has nothing to do with this..

Comment: As a side note: even if the CPU throws an exception, the OS might be able to emulate the misaligned access transparently for the process (which is again one magnitude slower than the hardware emulation)

Comment: @brhans I tried on an online compiler. I guess this is target specific but why?

Comment: removed my comments as this seems to turn into travesty. Hope you can get an answer. Cheers

Comment: thank you @formerlyknownas_463035818

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When running this code, I would expect it to fail. Why is it not?

Because:

1. The behaviour of the program is undefined<sup>1</sup>. There is no guarantee of failure<sup>2</sup>.
2. You may be using a system whose CPU supports misaligned access. As far as I understand, x86 for example performs misaligned reads and writes; they are merely slower than aligned ones (this does not apply to SIMD instructions though).

---

C++ standard says (quoting the latest draft):

<sup>1</sup>

> [basic.lval]
>
> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar ([conv.qual]) to one of the following types **the behavior is undefined**:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> - a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.

`uint16_t` is none of those listed exceptional types in this case (well, it *could* be on some system that has 16 bit byte, but not in general, and probably not on the server that runs the online compiler, and such system probably wouldn't provide `uint8_t`).

<sup>2</sup>

> [defns.undefined]
>
> behavior for which this document imposes no requirements

Note the lack of any guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

> When running this code, I would expect it to fail. Why is it not?

The program has undefined behavior as a result of strict-aliasing violations, but that doesn't mean it is obligated to fail (see "undefined"). From an alignment perspective, it is nowhere required that accessing a value through a pointer that does not have the natural alignment for its target type must fail, although that is one case that falls largely under the umbrella of the strict aliasing rule.  Whether such an access attempt actually does fail typically depends on the hardware on which the program runs.

Comment: Accessing through a misaligned pointer has nothing to do with strict aliasing. It's actually "unspecified" behaviour (As per [expr.static.cast/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13): "If the original pointer value represents the address A of a byte in memory and A does not satisfy the alignment requirement of T, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified."), so is implementation defined.

Comment: @Artyer The example program does not merely access through a misaligned pointer, but a pointer of incompatible type. That's why strict-aliasing is violated. Just because the pointer value is merely unspecified, doesn't mean that accessing through the misaligned pointer isn't UB.

Comment: @Artyer, as eerorika says, strict aliasing is violated not by the cast, but by dereferencing its result.  Violating strict aliasing is inherent in the mechanism by which the OP's code attempts to perform misaligned accesses, and regardless of the result of the cast or its definedness, the behavior of the attempts to access the pointed-to objects exhibit UB.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly happens depends on the platform used (cpu architecture and operating system).

There are several possibilities:

1. The architecture does not have a natural word alignment at all, so all accesses are considered aligned.
2. The CPU handles the unaligned access internally by performing several aligned accesses and constructing the result (slow).
3. The CPU detects the unaligned access and throws an exception. The operating system catches this exception and emulates the unaligned access *in software* (slower!).

Linux, for example, has this option for several arm architectures, it can even be chosen, if the unaligned access should be ignored, fixed, or signalled, optionally accompanied by a warning in the kernel log (see kernel source file `arch/arm/mm/alignment.c`.

4. The alignment results in a CPU exception and the process is signalled.
   On Linux, the process is usually terminated with a **SIGBUS** in that case.

Summary: Avoiding unaligned access is the safe side, but on most platforms, it will still work one way or the other.

Comment: nice detailed answer. Could you develop the first point? what do you mean?

Comment: @GuillaumeD As far as I know, for example some PowerPC CPUs do not care about alignment at all, fetching words from even or odd addresses does not make a difference, neither internally nor visible.